# Which of the following is True among the 4?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Following is a MCQ question I am having trouble with. Only 1 option is true from the following.

A) $\sin \alpha>\frac{\cos \alpha-\sin\beta}{\beta-\alpha}>\cos \beta ; For 0<\alpha<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

B) $\sin \alpha>\frac{\cos \alpha-\sin\beta}{\beta-\alpha}>\sin \beta ; For 0<\alpha<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

C) $\tan \alpha<\frac{\cos \alpha-\sin\beta}{\beta-\alpha}<\tan \beta ; For 0<\alpha<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

D) None of these.

Answer given is B. But can someone please tell me, $\sin \theta$ being a increasing function in $1^{st}$ Quadrant $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. How can $\sin \alpha$ be greater than $\sin \beta$  with $\beta>\alpha$.

Guidance Required. Thank you

Comment: Try with $\alpha=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say D - none of these.

A is not true
because we can choose
$\alpha$ and $\beta$
independently to make
$\sin \alpha < \cos \beta$.

B is not true because,
as you stated,
$\sin$ is increasing on
$(0, \pi/2)$.

C is not true
for the same reason as A:
we can choose
$\alpha$ and $\beta$
independently.

Therefore
the only possibility is D.